# How do you copy a String to the system clipboard in java?

Tags: java, swing, awt, clipboard

I have a `JTextArea` and would like to have a button that when clicked will copy the entire contents of the `JTextArea` to the `System` clipboard so that I can do Ctrl-V in any other program.  I have tried this but with no luck. Here is an example of something I've tried:

```
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection("This is a clipping");
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents( stringSelection, null );
```

Comment: And what happened? Did it throw an exception? Did it replace the clipboard with a blank string? Did it not do anything to the clipboard?

Comment: It did nothing to the clipboard at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ClipBoard` requires a [ClipboardOwner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/ClipboardOwner.html) for the copy action to take effect. This interface is often implemented by the current "pasting" class:

```
clipboard.setContents( stringSelection, myClipboardOwner);
```

[Example](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=82)

Comment: When I run the example program you linked, I see that the output is correct in that it prints what it put into the clipboard, but then if I paste in chrome for example, the "blah blah blah" isn't in my clipboard.

Comment: What do you mean paste in Chrome, paste into the URL field? I guess you're running Windows?

Comment: Yes, into the URL field. And I'm running Linux Mint.

Comment: Ok, I know there are some JVM issues with Mint. This worked fine under Windows.

Comment: That was very strange....I ran it in Windows and it worked and then when I went back to mint and tried it again it worked too. I didn't change a thing, so that's strange. Thank you for your help anyway.